# Splitting a string if a word does NOT have any numbers

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a string into words on white-spaces or any special character. But, if the word before AND after the split contains a number, and it is not a white-space character, then I DON'T want it to split.

> "abc abc-def a2b-def a2b-d3f"
>
> Should become - (notice the last word)
>
> "abc", " ", "abc", "-", "def", " ", "a2b", "-", "def", " ", "a2b-d3f"

I tried

```
b = "abc abc-def a2b-def a2b-d3f ab2-3cd"
print(re.split(r"((?<=\D)[\W]|[\W](?=\D)|\s)",b))
print(re.split(r"((?<!\b\w*\d\w*\b)[\W]|[\W](?!\b\w*\d\w*\b)|\s)",b))
```

The first one sort of works, but it only considers the last and first character of the previous or next word respectively. It maintained "ab2-3cd" as a single word, but it wouldn't work for "a2b-c3d".

The second one gives me an error "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" because it doesn't allow me to use * in look-back or look-ahead.

Please help me out!

EDIT: the words can be of arbitrary length, "abcdef".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\b(?=\w*?\d)\w+(?:[\W_](?=\w*?\d)\w+)*|[a-zA-Z]+|[\W_]+', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WBhSz1/1). [This](https://regex101.com/r/WBhSz1/2) regex must be safer though. Maybe the last `|[\W_]+` must be [without a `+`](https://regex101.com/r/WBhSz1/3).

Comment: I understand that a runnable piece of code is expected, but I don't understand the downvote to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "abc abc-def a2b-def a2b-d3f"

s = re.split(r'(?:(?<=[\da-z]{3})(\s|-)(?=[a-z]{3})|(?:(?<=[a-z]{3})(\s|-)(?=[a-z\d]{3})))', s)
s = [i for i in s if i is not None]
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
['abc', ' ', 'abc', '-', 'def', ' ', 'a2b', '-', 'def', ' ', 'a2b-d3f']
```

EDIT:

import re

```
s = "a2dc abc axx2b-dss3f abc-def a2b-abc a2b-d3f"

s = re.split(r'(\s|-)(?=[a-z]+(?:-|\s))', s)
out = []
for w in s:
    out.extend(re.split(r'(?<=[a-z\d])(\s)(?=[a-z\d])', w))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['a2dc', ' ', 'abc', ' ', 'axx2b-dss3f', ' ', 'abc', '-', 'def', ' ', 'a2b', '-', 'abc', ' ', 'a2b-d3f']
```

Comment: The words can be of an arbitrary length. I've edited the question with this now.

Comment: @vivek Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all patterns matching ptrn `r'\w+|\W+'` from the words that match the pattern `r'\d\w*\W+\w*\d'`

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = "abc abc-def a2b-def a2b-d3f"
>>> [w for s in txt.split() for w in ([s] if re.search(r'\d\w*\W+\w*\d', s) else re.findall(r'\w+|\W+', s)) + [' ']]
['abc', ' ', 'abc', '-', 'def', ' ', 'a2b', '-', 'def', ' ', 'a2b-d3f', ' ']
```